# Can't load Directive in lazy module from other NgModule

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am having a problem loading a Directive and getting the dreaded `Can't bind to 'hapPluginSlot' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.`

In my project I have the following setup

```
app
  - shared
      shared.module
      - directives
          directives.module
          plugin-slot.directive
  - protected
      protected.module
      - home
          home.module (lazy loaded)
          home.component
```

An I have the following code in the respective files

**plugin-slot.directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[hapPluginSlot]'
})
export class PluginSlotDirective {

  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() type: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.name, this.type);
  }

}
```

**directives.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* Angular Imports */
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PluginSlotDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    PluginSlotDirective
  ]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }
```

**shared.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* Angular Imports */
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
    /* Application Imports */
    PipesModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PipesModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

I am importing `SharedModule` into my `home.module` as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule, //<--- shared module imported here
    HomeRouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

And using the directive in the component template as below

```
...
<mat-nav-list>
  <ng-container [hapPluginSlot] type="route">
  </ng-container>
</mat-nav-list>
...
```

And finally get to the question, I have checked and checked over this code and I am 100% certain that I have all the `imports` and `exports` in all the right places. Why am I getting this error?

I have even tried stripping back to just load the directive in the `AppModule` and `AppComponent` thinking it may be something to do with lazy loaded modules, I am clearly missing something but I cannot see the wood for the trees as I have been staring at this for what feels like an eternity.

I anyone can spot the problem then please, for the sake of the children, please point it out to me?

Comment: Did you try `<ng-container hapPluginSlot type="route">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a syntax issue, first solution is to use your directive like this :

```
<ng-container hapPluginSlot type="route"></ng-container>
```

You could change the directive declaration to use a more compact syntax :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[hapPluginSlot]'
})
export class PluginSlotDirective {
   ...
   @Input('hapPluginSlot') type: string;
```

And call it like this :

```
<ng-container [hapPluginSlot]="route"></ng-container>
```